# Fastest way to sync and start using Monero GUI wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

What is the fastest way to sync and start using Monero GUI wallet and how to do it?

If anyone has tried various methods, what is the different time taken for each method to start using Monero GUI wallet.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions provided [here](https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-speed-up-initial-blockchain-sync) to download the raw blockchain and import it. The raw blockchain is somewhere around 4GB, and the import process for me took a couple of hours or so.

You'll need to be somewhat familiar with using the command line and installing packages using Homebrew, because you may need to install additional packages (such as wget) if you haven't already. I was somewhat familiar with using the command line and got stuck a couple of times, but was able to Google my way through it pretty easily whenever an error came up.

Note that these instructions include the process needed to set up a wallet in the command line, so if you've already got a wallet you won't need to do that.

If you need instructions on how to create a wallet in the GUI you can go [here](https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-use-the-monero-gui-wallet).

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply, i m doing blockchain.raw import now and used --verify 0 , and now it is reading the 4.5 gb file, following commands here
https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-speed-up-initial-blockchain-sync

However the reading of blockchain.raw file is taking some time. I will be back if i have doubt after it has read all the block chain data from blockchain.raw file, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question has been asked previously on StackExchange and answered here:

[What is the fastest way to synchronize the daemon?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-synchronize-the-daemon/2762#2762)

Again, the process does require familiarity with the command line.