# Changing block-sync-size within GUI or running monerod

Tags: synchronization

This [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/4497/123) explains how to start the daemon with a specified block-sync-size:

> ./monerod --block-sync-size 10

How can I do the same thing from the Monero GUI or from a Monero daemon that is already running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, to clarify for the readers, this flag will change the batch of blocks that is fetched to 10, from a default of 200 blocks per batch.

> How can I do the same thing from the Monero GUI

If you are using the GUI, simply add `--block-sync-size 10` as daemon startup flag. You can do this on the `Settings` page of the GUI. Note that you need to restart the GUI in order to utilize the flag.

> from a Monero daemon that is already running?

You cannot add the flag to a daemon that is already running, as this is a flag that should be added upon startup.

The startup flag is added as follows if you use the CLI tools.

On Windows make sure to launch it from the command line. Go to the folder `monerod` is located and make sure your cursor isn't located on any of the files. Subsequently do SHIFT + right click and it will give you an option to "Open command window here". Lastly, type the following command:

`monerod --block-sync-size 10`

On Linux and Mac OS X you should use the terminal to launch monerod. Note that this has to be done from the directory monerod is located in. The command is as follows:

`./monerod --block-sync-size 10`

Comment: Should specify the current default in the text (200) so readers understand what it is being changed from, by this adjustment.  And maybe why, or under what conditions it is helpful

Comment: Good suggestion. Edited.

Comment: I really want to be able to change this via the daemon without restarting in the same way I would type `limit 100000` or `in_peers 20`. Is there anything preventing this? Would it be worth taking a shot at adding this functionality?

Comment: @errata - I suppose it may be worthwhile as long as it does not add much code complexity.