# F exception while reading from file, height=2521799: Error in deserialization of chunk

Tags: blockchain-import

I have been following the [What is the fastest way to synchronize the daemon?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-synchronize-the-daemon) post to import the blockchain.

I download the `blockchain.raw` successfully but I got error at importing the last block:

```
$ monero-blockchain-import --input-file blockchain.raw
2024-03-06 07:38:23.208 I Starting...
2024-03-06 07:38:23.208 I database: LMDB
2024-03-06 07:38:23.208 I verify:  true
2024-03-06 07:38:23.208 I batch:   true  batch size: 5000
2024-03-06 07:38:23.208 I resume:  true
2024-03-06 07:38:23.208 I nettype: mainnet
2024-03-06 07:38:23.208 I bootstrap file path: blockchain.raw
2024-03-06 07:38:23.208 I database path:       /home/<user_name>/.bitmonero
2024-03-06 07:38:23.209 I Loading blockchain from folder /home/<use_name>/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
2024-03-06 07:38:24.167 I Loading checkpoints
2024-03-06 07:38:24.167 I bootstrap file recognized
2024-03-06 07:38:24.167 I bootstrap::file_info size: 4
2024-03-06 07:38:24.167 I bootstrap file v1.0
2024-03-06 07:38:24.167 I bootstrap magic size: 4
2024-03-06 07:38:24.167 I bootstrap header size: 1024
2024-03-06 07:38:24.167 I bootstrap::blocks_info size: 6
2024-03-06 07:38:24.167 I bootstrap first block:0
2024-03-06 07:38:24.167 I bootstrap last block:2554143
2024-03-06 07:38:24.167 I Scanning blockchain from bootstrap file...
block height: 2554143               
Done scanning bootstrap file
Full header length: 1028 bytes
Scanned for blocks: 92359691963 bytes
Total:              92359692991 bytes
Number of blocks: 2554144

2024-03-06 07:40:03.185 I bootstrap file last block number: 2554143 (zero-based height)  total blocks: 2554144

Preparing to read blocks...

2024-03-06 07:40:03.185 I bootstrap file recognized
2024-03-06 07:40:03.185 I bootstrap::file_info size: 4
2024-03-06 07:40:03.185 I bootstrap file v1.0
2024-03-06 07:40:03.185 I bootstrap magic size: 4
2024-03-06 07:40:03.185 I bootstrap header size: 1024
2024-03-06 07:40:03.185 I bootstrap::blocks_info size: 6
2024-03-06 07:40:03.185 I bootstrap first block:0
2024-03-06 07:40:03.185 I bootstrap last block:2554143
2024-03-06 07:40:03.185 I start block: 2520001  stop block: 2554143
2024-03-06 07:40:03.185 I Reading blockchain from bootstrap file...

2024-03-06 07:40:03.513 F exception while reading from file, height=2521799: Error in deserialization of chunk
```

I tried using the `--dangerous-unverified-import 0` and `--dangerous-unverified-import 1` options with no vain. I also think that the downloaded blockchain is complete, see the `wget` output:

```
$ wget -c --progress=bar https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw
--2024-03-06 08:40:45--  https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolving downloads.getmonero.org (downloads.getmonero.org)... 163.171.147.15, 163.171.132.42
Connecting to downloads.getmonero.org (downloads.getmonero.org)|163.171.147.15|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.
```

Could someone kindly help me to resolve the importing problem?

EDIT:

For more information, I tried the `mb_stat` command to check the inconsistencies in the blocks:

```
$ mdb_stat -ea ~/.bitmonero/lmdb/
Environment Info
  Map address: (nil)
  Map size: 136582162432
  Page size: 4096
  Max pages: 33345254
  Number of pages used: 32401144
  Last transaction ID: 496
  Max readers: 126
  Number of readers used: 0
Status of Main DB
  Tree depth: 1
  Branch pages: 0
  Leaf pages: 1
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 18
Status of alt_blocks
  Tree depth: 0
  Branch pages: 0
  Leaf pages: 0
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 0
Status of block_heights
  Tree depth: 1
  Branch pages: 0
  Leaf pages: 1
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 2519040
Status of block_info
  Tree depth: 1
  Branch pages: 0
  Leaf pages: 1
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 2519040
Status of blocks
  Tree depth: 4
  Branch pages: 1167
  Leaf pages: 261949
  Overflow pages: 72974
  Entries: 2519040
Status of hf_versions
  Tree depth: 3
  Branch pages: 56
  Leaf pages: 12349
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 2519040
Status of output_amounts
  Tree depth: 4
  Branch pages: 540
  Leaf pages: 80668
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 66989662
Status of output_txs
  Tree depth: 1
  Branch pages: 0
  Leaf pages: 1
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 66989662
Status of properties
  Tree depth: 1
  Branch pages: 0
  Leaf pages: 1
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 2
Status of spent_keys
  Tree depth: 1
  Branch pages: 0
  Leaf pages: 1
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 59117829
Status of tx_indices
  Tree depth: 1
  Branch pages: 0
  Leaf pages: 1
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 21424060
Status of tx_outputs
  Tree depth: 4
  Branch pages: 1014
  Leaf pages: 227590
  Overflow pages: 2383
  Entries: 21424060
Status of txpool_blob
  Tree depth: 0
  Branch pages: 0
  Leaf pages: 0
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 0
Status of txpool_meta
  Tree depth: 0
  Branch pages: 0
  Leaf pages: 0
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 0
Status of txs
  Tree depth: 0
  Branch pages: 0
  Leaf pages: 0
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 0
Status of txs_prunable
  Tree depth: 4
  Branch pages: 23114
  Leaf pages: 5200409
  Overflow pages: 19099551
  Entries: 21424060
Status of txs_prunable_hash
  Tree depth: 4
  Branch pages: 1060
  Leaf pages: 238107
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 19286639
Status of txs_prunable_tip
  Tree depth: 0
  Branch pages: 0
  Leaf pages: 0
  Overflow pages: 0
  Entries: 0
Status of txs_pruned
  Tree depth: 4
  Branch pages: 9355
  Leaf pages: 2104324
  Overflow pages: 641658
  Entries: 21424060
```

However, I am not sure how to verify if the blocks are consistent or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the exception is because the blockchain was not the latest. I had to synchronize using the monero daemon after loading the raw block chain:

```
monerod --block-sync-size 10
```

I used 10 block size as other post suggested it is the fastest. Yet, I had to wait for additional 6 hours (apart from 8-10 hours of loading the raw blockchain) for syncing the remaining blockchain.

> Note: As of now, the `data.mdb` size is 179.4 GiB.